# Belongs on Physics

Tags: discussion, migration

Currently the only option to migrate when closing a Off Topic is to Meta. Would it be possible to add some more, esp. to Physics (or perhaps other science forums as well)?

Answer (score 1):

List of questions migrated to Physics:

- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5330/is-apparent-horizon-curvature-lesser-due-to-refraction-of-light-in-the-atmosphere
- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/are-scientists-missing-the-point-with-distant-cosmic-objects-or-is-it-just-me
- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2615/has-quantum-entanglement-indeed-been-demonstrated-to-be-able-to-take-place-over-i
- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2254/troll-physics-buoyancy-for-infinite-power-migrated
- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1850/can-you-see-yourself-in-a-mirror-when-you-are-riding-on-top-of-a-light-stream-m
- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/is-time-travel-possible-closed
- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1400/what-could-make-the-switl-materials-behave-like-this-migrated
- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1375/what-is-in-the-space-between-a-nucleus-of-an-atom-and-its-electrons-migrated
- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1152/if-a-credit-card-wont-read-when-swiped-does-wrapping-it-in-plastic-actually-hel
- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/does-the-math-work-out-for-there-being-enough-time-for-the-formation-of-the-heavi

I haven't checked what happened to those questions on Physics.

Comment: They have all been well received except 2254 (troll physics) which was closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

To get a migration path we have to show the SE team that it is really useful. So we would need to collect a list of questions that have been migrated (or should have been) to Physics to get that path.

For our low question volume it is also no problems for moderators to perform all migrations, so don't hesitate to flag questions for migration if they are off-topic here.